# How do I get some parts in string as group in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to get some parts as group in my string using regex. I tried many solutions but they did not work.

Part of my whole string:

```
...

{"name":"AE102-Fundamentals of Automotive Engineering","short":"AE102","color":"#00C0FF","picture":"",
"timeoff":[
[
["1"]]],"id":"-696","picture_url":""},

{"name":"AE202 lab-Fuels and Combustion lab","short":"AE202 lab","color":"#FF5050","picture":"",
"timeoff":[
[
["1"]]],"id":"-697","picture_url":""},

{"name":"AE202-Fuels and Combustion","short":"AE202","color":"#CCFFFF","picture":"",
"timeoff":[
[
["1"]]],"id":"-698","picture_url":""},

...
```

Output should be like:

```
[
   {"name":"...","short":"...","id":"..."},
   {"name":"...","short":"...","id":"..."},
   ....
]
```

Additionally, The platform is node js.

Comment: What regex did you use?

Comment: I used that /\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\"[^]\"short\"\:\"(.*?)\"(.|\n)*?\"id\"\:\"(.*?)\"/g but it is . not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression for this - parse the JSON with `JSON.parse` instead, and use `.map` to extract the desired properties from each row:

```js
function parse() {
  const obj = JSON.parse(input);
  const newRows = obj.map(({ name, short, id }) => ({ name, short, id }));
  console.log(newRows);
}

const input = `[{
    "name": "AE102-Fundamentals of Automotive Engineering",
    "short": "AE102",
    "color": "#00C0FF",
    "picture": "",
    "timeoff": [
      [
        ["1"]
      ]
    ],
    "id": "-696",
    "picture_url": ""
  },

  {
    "name": "AE202 lab-Fuels and Combustion lab",
    "short": "AE202 lab",
    "color": "#FF5050",
    "picture": "",
    "timeoff": [
      [
        ["1"]
      ]
    ],
    "id": "-697",
    "picture_url": ""
  },

  {
    "name": "AE202-Fuels and Combustion",
    "short": "AE202",
    "color": "#CCFFFF",
    "picture": "",
    "timeoff": [
      [
        ["1"]
      ]
    ],
    "id": "-698",
    "picture_url": ""
  }
]`;
parse();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's way more efficient and usable.